# fwrite() is not writing data specified number of times

Tags: c, file-io

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE* out = fopen("out.txt", "w");

    string buffer = "Milo Banana\n";

    fwrite(buffer, 12, 12, out);

    fclose(out);
}
```

the above code does not write data 12 times in the out.txt file but when i use a loop it works

```
int main(void)
    {
    FILE* out = fopen("out.txt", "w");

    string buffer = "Milo Banana\n";

    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        fwrite(buffer, 12, 1, out);
    }

    fclose(out);
}
```

the above code works and write "milo banana" 12 times in the out.txt file but
why does the first code doesn't work isn't it true by definition

Comment: `fwrite` effectively multiplies the two size arguments, so in your case, you were attempting to write 144 consecutive bytes of data.  So you were reading past the end of the string.  Did you look at the file size?  There was probably garbage after the expected string.

Comment: the C language does not contain a type `string`.  It does contain a type `char`.  so where is the `string` type coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't true by definition.

[N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 7.21.8.2 The fwrite function says:

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> size_t fwrite(const void * restrict ptr,
>      size_t size, size_t nmemb,
>      FILE * restrict stream);
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> 2 The fwrite function writes, from the array pointed to by ptr, up to nmemb elements
> whose size is specified by size, to the stream pointed to by stream.

The "number of elements" parameter is for writing consecutive elements of an array, not for repeatedly writing the same data.